# Create a single application that can act as a service (using topshelf) and an interactive application

Tags: .net, topshelf

Previously when I have created Windows services in .NET, I create the application so that it can run as a service or as an interactive application (it identifies how it should run depending on the presence of a command line argument - for instance --service.

I am looking at using TopShelf, and wonder if this has this functionality. I haven't yet found anything, but wonder if anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

When a Topshelf service is run, the context is automatically handled. Just run it without any parameters and it runs as a console application. When you execute `myService.exe install` it will setup everything that's needed to run as service. You just execute the service via the service manager then.

Comment: Thanks - can I still pass parameters for my own use - and what parameters does TopShelf 'reserve' for its own user - e.g. install?

Comment: Topshelf attempts to parse all the parameters, I don't think you can pass any. If you need to configure it that way normally we would suggest leveraging the app.config. http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html

Comment: In current versions you can now use `x.AddCommandLineDefinition(...)` within your HostFactory.New() or .Run()